# A NPM package written in Typescript - defining the public-facing API

Tags: typescript

I want to publish a npm package written in Typescript.

As far as typing goes, my current approach is to simply let `tsc` generate a `.d.ts` for every file, via the `delaration:true` setting. I've heard you need a *single* index.d.ts (which I have emitted once with dts-generator, and it didn't seem to provide any typing assistance to IDEs), though the typescript's native map seem to work okayish.

I tried importing all public APIs into `src/index.ts` and exporting it out, then setting the `main` in `package.json` to `dist/index.js`, however it seems that IDEs prefer to dig deep into my package's files (for example, on typing `MainClass` WebStorm suggests `my-package/dist/MainClass` and `my-package/dist`), rather than simply import the package itself, such as `import {MainClass} from "myPackage"`. The latter *does work* (probably due to everything being re-exported from `index/index.js`, nevertheless the fact that IDEs show such suggestions makes me think something's wrong with my package's structure.

[Here is the link to the repo.](https://github.com/vlopp/ggclient)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try the following

- Keep one index.ts "barrel" file that exports all of your public APIs (e.g. `src/index.ts`)
- `delaration:true` is fine, keep it on :)
- compile with tsc into a separate folder (e.g. `./dist`). You can .gitignore it
- In your package.json you should do two things:

  - "main" should point to your compiled index.js file (e.g. `dist/index.js`
  - "types" should point to your generated type definition index (e.g. `dist/index.d.ts`. **I think that's the missing point in your case.**
    You can read more on the topic [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html).

The import now should look like:

```
import { MyClass } from "myPackage"
```